# How to use multithread option on single table backup using mydumper

Tags: backup, mysql

I'm trying to use mydumper and myloader to perform a backup and restore activity of the MySQL database. Below is the use case

We have 1 database, around 2 TB, out of which 1 table is around 1.3 TB. Now I want to take a backup of a single table using the multithreads option, and I used the below query, but I don't see multiple threads at the database level when I run show processlist.

```
mydumper -h host_name -u username --password= password -P 3306 --tables-list=db_name.table_name -t 14  -o /path
```

and also below

```
mydumper -h host_name -u username --password= password -P 3306 --tables-list=db_name.table_name --rows=1000000 -t 14  -o /path
```

So how to achieve multiple threading on a single table while taking the backup and also while restoring as well?